# _POST data not being returned

Tags: php, post, linux-mint

_POST not working.

I don't need to know how to read it. I need to know how to have it work.

I have spend three days reading and trying answer from this website.

this is on a fresh install of php.7.3. mint 20

file name is temp.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $postct = extract ( $_POST ) ;
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $getct = extract ( $_GET ) ;
}

$php_inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($php_inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini is: ' . $php_inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']))
{
  $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
  $val= $_REQUEST['texta'];
  echo $val;
}
var_dump ($_POST) ;
?>
<head>
</head> 
<body>
<form name="test" target="./temp.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
    <?php
    if (!isset( $texta )) { 
        $texta = "default_text" ;
    }  
    echo "<br>text is $texta" ;
    echo "<br><input type=\"text\" value=$texta>" ;

    echo "<br><input type=\"submit\", value=\"Submit\">" ;
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your inputs don't have a name, so you can not read the POST data. Please add the name="texta" attribute to your input and the name="submit" to your button.

Comment: Give your form inputs a name, ie `<input type="text" name="texta" value="$texta" />`. You should then be able  to get that value in `$_POST['texta']`.

Comment: What they said. This is something you learn if you study a basic html forms tutorial.

Comment: And I solved the problem - I changed to Debian linux - it was a very slow install but very accurate; the apache2 installed per the install KOOL